# Getting the content inside a span based on its class and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to use -

```
console.log('the favorite count:', $('.favorite-count#'+id).text());
```

The id variable is correct but when I log it out, it's logging out blank.

This is what the html looks like -

[image]

highlighted is the value im trying to get and change in my code

Comment: u could give us the html as code instead :) just remove the link u want to be cencored.

Comment: does it matter? it was just easier for me to take a snippet

Comment: With a real piece of html-code we could build a demonstrator that could highlight was works and what does not. One things springs to my mind directly: `id`s are always unique, so the mention of the class is not necessary in your selector. `$('#'+id)` should be enough.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Your code will work definitely fine if you have the right id https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/113/

Comment: If you're going to query by id, just use the id (e.g., `$('#' + id)`) since they have to be unique in the document anyway. Adding the class to the selector will just slow the process down.

Comment: I also use the id for in the img, do you think that can be why?

Comment: yes and no ;) here on SO we should always try to provide at least a minimum of code in text so others can try it out, but for this question it's not that hard to type it, actually.

Comment: So yeah the reason it wasnt working because I realized I used the same id for two separate elements. I just fixed it by prefixing the second time i use it with "count"+id

Comment: Don't put images of your HTML in your question, people would not be able to find the text "favorite-count" without laborious reading. ALSO you didn't include enough for anyone but you to be able to discern that the id was not unique. See: "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using the same id in two separate places, so the second one I just prefixed with 'count' and now it's working okay.

Comment: Ids should be unique. I'm glad you fixed it, but, say you only selected `$('.favorite-count')`, in that case you can refer to the first instance's text with `$('.favorite-count')[0].text`.

Answer (score 0):

Your html also looks a little malformed. Your image tag is not closed but has an unclosed < span> inside.

As for your selector try `$('.favorite-count [id^=' + id + ']').text()`